# Is ICD-9 to ICD-10 migration in health care industry another Y2K-like opportunity?

Tags: healthcare

The World Health Organisation publish the [International Statistical Classification of Diseases and Related Health Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Statistical_Classification_of_Diseases_and_Related_Health_Problems) (ICD). A new version, [ICD-10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10) was published in 1992.

I work in health care IT. Recently there has been quite a few advertisments and news articles that claim the ICD-9 to ICD-10 migration to be done in October 2013 is a Y2K-like opportunity.

To quote one below

> As stated in an article titled, Issues Surrounding the Proposed 
>     Implementation of ICD-10, “In effect, this will be the most significant 
>     overhaul of the medical coding system since the advent of computers 
>     ... even more costly and involved than Y2K or HIPAA preparedness efforts”.

-- [source](http://www.asco.org/ASCO/ArticleASCO/Cancer%20Policy%20and%20Clinical%20Affairs/Microsoft%20Word%20-%20ICD_9_CM_to_ICD_10_CM_Coding_Transition.pdf)

Is it conversion step really big that it is comparable to Y2K?